# Vector Declaration Syntax

Tags: java, vector

I'm new to Java and am stuck with this syntax differences between Vector declaration.

```
Vector<Object> v = new Vector<>(SIZE);
```

and this one

```
Vector v = new Vector(SIZE, GROWABLESIZE);
```

I know that both of these will create a new Vector of Object type (castable to other types) and can store upto SIZE number of Objects but how do they differ internally/functionally?

I learnt the first one while working with JTable for a college project and the later syntax was taught in lectures (and in books). I'm unable to differentiate between the two.

Comment: If the later was taught in lectures and books then the lectures and books are old and or out of date. Generics were introduced in java 1.5 I believe, which came out quite a while ago. The bracketed syntax is preferred since it tells the compiler which type we are working with and allows it to detect errors at compile time (or write time in a decent IDE).

Comment: Also vector is a bad choice for modern java. It has synchronization baked in I believe, therefore you will incur that overhead even if you didnt need it. `ArrayList` is the one to use.

Comment: please check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) - it should be explained there (at least the arguments)!

Comment: @PaulRooney Those books aren't old but may be out of date. But most of the online tutorials like this one, (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_vector_class.htm) , they have identical implementation. I don't wanna follow other resources but the official Oracle documentation is not much beginner friendly. Can you suggest some better resources?

Comment: I couldnt recommend any beginner friendly books. I came from many years doing c++ so was able to start from a fairly advanced stage. Effective java is the one to aim for but you may need another book to get you to that level.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior difference at runtime is that the second one specifies a value for `capacityIncrement` :

> **capacityIncrement** : the amount by which the capacity is increased when
>   the vector overflows

The difference at compile time is that the second uses a raw type. Which means that the compiler will emit warning about that.
Even if  you want to put/get `Object` in this vector (which is in general a bad practice), declaring a generic type that is `Vector<Object>` is clearer and show you intention.

So this :

```
Vector<Object> v = new Vector<>(SIZE);
```

or that :

```
Vector<Object> v = new Vector<>(SIZE, GROWABLESIZE);
```

are better.

But generally you don't want to use `Vector` that is a thread safe legacy class, still present mainly for retro-compatibility reasons.
The `Collections.synchronizedList()` static method is generally a better/more flexible way to make a `List` instance thread safe.